# Error: Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, flask

**Task in general:**

The user should type in a text and the server should receive this text.

**Problem**

I get this error message when i run the code in VScode below.

What i am doing wrong?

My code files:

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>home</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>login</h1>

<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5500/login" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="write your text here" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**local.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')
   
@app.route('/')
def index():
    #return 'tesddt'
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    print(request.form['name']) # should display 'website'
    return render_template('login.html') #'Received !' + website # response to your request.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=5500)
```

I use this Url: http://127.0.0.1:5500/login in my browser.

Comment: When you type that URL in your browser, there are no forms, so your `request.form` is going to fail.  You probably want to have one function for GET (that assumes no data) and one for POST (that expects a form).

Comment: Are there any errors in the web server error log?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>login</h1>

<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="write your text here" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Use the above code and check